# how generate dynamic route reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i am trying to generate dynamic route from json.

there is my static router

```
     <Router history={newHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent}/>
            <Route path="/foo" component={FooComponent}/>
            <Route path="/bar" component={BarComponent}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

in my json result i get route:{home,foo,bar}

in my case i try to loop on my tab route and creat route without succes ... 
any idea ?

there is one of my try

```
listRoute(jsonRoute){

    var tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < jsonRoute.length; i++){
        tmp +=  <Route path="/jsonRoute[i]" component={TestComponent}/>;
    }
    return (
        tmp
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router history={newHistory}>
                {
                    this.listRoute()
                }
            </Router>
        </div>

    );
}
```

thx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an Array in `listRoute` function:

```
listRoute(jsonRoute){
    var tmp = [];
    for (i = 0; i < jsonRoute.length; i++){
        // you need to concatenate `i` variable as well:
        tmp.push(<Route path={"/" + jsonRoute[i]} component={TestComponent}/>);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: And in general try to move away from `var` and use `let` and `const` to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @Jayce444 in that case we are not polluting global namespace using `var` keyword, as it's defined in the scope of the function

Comment: Yeah I know that's why I said 'in general'. It's best not to use it in any situation and just get used to the other ones that way you reduce the risk of using `var` in a potentially bad spot. But you're right here it doesn't matter

Comment: thx a lot you save me. ps : can you upvote my question i'm new and i need 20 of rep to access to the chat thx a lot

Comment: @1ven it's perfect but i change  tmp.push(<Route path={"/jsonRoute" + i} component={TestComponent}/>); to  tmp.push(<Route path= path={"/" + jsonRoute[i]} component={TestComponent}/>);

Comment: @tetar yeah, you're correct, I've not noticed that initially. Updated the answer